# Getting a 403 error using Scrapy Request

Tags: python, request, scrapy

When I use the Python requests module for the following HTTP request, it returns a dict of exactly what I need:

```
import requests

payload = {'x-algolia-application-id':'Q0TMLOPF1J','x-algolia-api-key':'30a0c84a152d179ea8aa1a7a59374d08', 'hitsPerPage':'40', 'numericFilters': ['startdate > 1511095966851'],'facets': '*' }  

url = 'https://q0tmlopf1j-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/sitecore-events'

r = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
```

However when I instead try to implement this as a scrapy Request so I can parse the results:

```
def start_requests(self):
    payload = {'x-algolia-application-id':'Q0TMLOPF1J','x-algolia-api-key':'30a0c84a152d179ea8aa1a7a59374d08', 'hitsPerPage':'40', 'numericFilters': ['startdate > 1511095966851'],'facets': '*' }  

    url = 'https://q0tmlopf1j-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/sitecore-events'

    yield scrapy.Request(url,
                                   body=json.dumps(payload), 
                                   method='GET',
                                   callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self,response):
    # I want to parse the dict here
```

I get a 403 error. I know there is something simple I am doing wrong, what is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33747209/8150371

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this. It still gives a 403.

Comment: Specifically: the site API returns an error that the API key or application ID is invalid, which is not the case, since the same credentials work using requests.

Comment: check the url by printing after it is encoded

Comment: It is : https://q0tmlopf1j-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/sitecore-events/x-algolia-application-id=Q0TMLOPF1J&x-algolia-api-key=30a0c84a152d179ea8aa1a7a59374d08&hitsPerPage=40&facets=*, which is what returns the errors mentioned above.

Comment: you need to add `?` instead of `/` after sitescore-events , change to `https://q0tmlopf1j-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/sitecore-events?x-algolia-application-id=Q0TMLOPF1J&x-algolia-api-key=30a0c84a152d179ea8aa1a7a59374d08&hitsPerPage=40&facets=`

Comment: It still returns the same error.

Comment: compare it with `requests` url , you can access that url by `r.url`

Comment: This brought an interesting discovery: the dict element "'numericFilters': ['startdate > 1511095966851']" was not correctly converted to URL by Scrapy, which was the problem. Requests was stripping it out altogether. I removed it manually from the Scrapy request, since it was an inessential filter, and it works.

Comment: ok great :) ...

Answer (score -1):

I know you've "solved" the problem by leaving out a parameter, but the correct way to do this would be using a [FormRequest](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(
    url=url,
    method='GET',
    formdata=payload,
    callback=self.parse_item
)
```

Comment: Do you mean this would correctly parse the omitted parameter? It does not; it still returns the 403 error. It does work without it, however.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I get the same response as with requests.