# Getting wrong html content when trying to download a webpage using python requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, request

I am trying to download a URL something like "https://some.com/ATS/cgi-bin/view.pl?axm_f_qtr_ins_chk_bd_sds%20status%20P01".

I think that is because of the %20. Can you please help me with this encoding issue? The garbage webpage which gets downloaded is as attached. Also, I cannot use beautifulsoup. I am restricted only to requests package. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you need [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

Comment: Thanks Tushortz, but that did not help, still getting the same error

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747174/how-to-specify-parameters-on-a-request-using-scrapy

Comment: Share the code you are using to issue the request.